# Why is this mock failing? (from PHPUnit doc)

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I created the following test, using PHPUnit documentation, and it fails with the following message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Mock_SomeClass_97937e7a::doSomething().
```

What's wrong? This is the example from the documentation. I'm using PHPUnit 4.4.0.

```
<?php

class SomeClass
{

}

class SomeClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testStub()
    {
        // Create a stub for the SomeClass class.
        $stub = $this->getMockBuilder('SomeClass')
            ->getMock();

        // Configure the stub.
        $stub->method('doSomething')
            ->willReturn('foo');

        // Calling $stub->doSomething() will now return
        // 'foo'.
        $this->assertEquals('foo', $stub->doSomething());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doSomething` method is missing in SomeClass. You cannot mock a method that does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't change a thing :( Also there is no namespace used.

Comment: You're right. The problem is that you actually have no doSomething() method in your SomeClass... I don't know if I'm blind, but I swear I've seen it there ;)

Comment: Damned! Obviously I cannot mock a method that does not exists… Thanks bbankowski. Edit your answer and I'll vote it up.

Comment: You can mock methods that don't exist.  You just have to add a `setMethods` call to your MockBuilder.  This will set the methods that will be mocked.  So your mock becomes `$stub = $this->getMockBuilder('SomeClass')->setMethods(['doSomething'])->getMock();`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the snapshot:

- Declare the "doSomething" method on your "SomeClass" class.
- Use the "setMethods" routine after "getMockBuilder"
- Instead of willReturn, use "will($this->returnValue('foo'))".

Here's my code:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public function doSomething()
    {

    }
}

class StubTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testStub()
    {
        // Create a stub for the SomeClass class.
        $stub = $this->getMockBuilder('SomeClass')
                        ->setMethods(array('doSomething'))
                        ->getMock();

        // Configure the stub.
        $stub->expects($this->any())
                ->method('doSomething')
                ->will($this->returnValue('foo'));

        // Calling $stub->doSomething() will now return
        // 'foo'.
        $this->assertEquals('foo', $stub->doSomething());
    }
}
```